# Mock in java exception

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have this catch statement:

```
catch (NotFoundException ex) {
      ex.getError().setTitle(NOT_FOUND);
      throw new NotFoundException(resource, id, ex.getError());
}
```

How can I mock this exception? I've tried this

```
    when(service
        .filter(eq(any()), eq(any()), eq(any())))
        .thenThrow(new NotFoundException(anyString(), anyString()));`
```

But it gives me a null exception error because of this line:

```
ex.getError().setTitle(NOT_FOUND);
```

The constructor is:

```
  public NotFoundException(String resource, String id, Error error) {
    this.resource = resource;
    this.ids = Collections.singletonList(id);
    this.error = error;
  }
```

And I can't get the exception variable to set the title, or find an way to mock it.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
.thenThrow(new NotFoundException(anyString(), anyString()));
```

This isn't allowed: `anyString()` only stands directly in for the call in `when` and `verify`. In your call to filter, simply use `any()` rather than `eq(any())`, but you're otherwise using matchers in the correct place.

Furthermore, it looks like your system-under-test assumes that `ex.getError()` is non-null; it is likely that you'll need to pass in a useful Error instance as constructor parameter into the NotFoundException you create.

```java
.thenThrow(new NotFoundException("foo", "bar", new Error(/* ... */)))
```

Naturally, if your Error is difficult to create or work with, you might use a `mock(Error.class)` instead.

Comment: I've changed the anyString() to variables with values. But I don't have a constructor to make this behavior. I'm using junit and mockito on Spring.

Comment: @TryMe Is NotFoundException code you control (or that your company controls)? If it belongs to a library, could you tell us which library it's from? Ultimately, if your `catch` block expects a value to be populated and you can't supply it due to the implementation details of NotFoundException, that's nothing that Mockito or JUnit can help with.

Comment: Sorry, Jeff. The NotFoundException was actually made by me and it has a constructor. I've updated the question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @TryMe Ah! Then what I'd meant was that you should `thenThrow(new NotFoundException("foo", "bar", new Error(/* ... */)))` for whichever Error instance you need to construct. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jeff; This was blowing my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @TryMe You're welcome! I didn't catch before that you'd called `eq(any())`, though, which is wrong. I've updated my answer; if you get InvalidUseOfMatchersException later, this might be why.